# Как в Си определить тип переменной?

Tags: c

А именно, число или нет?

Comment: В каком контексте это нужно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно автор кода знает, какого типа переменная используется. Если переменная используется ошибочно, то либо во время компиляции, либо во время выполнения появляются ошибки.

В более сложных случаях требуются дополнительные меры по хранению типа. Например, есть функция

```
void func(void *p) {
    char x = *(char *)p;
}
```

Загодя сказать, на какую переменную указывает p не получится, она может быть какой угодно, например, double:

```
double d;

func((void *)&d);
```

Поэтому при необходимости заводят структуру

```
struct Z {
    // тип
    // переменная
}
```

и работают с ней.

Comment: Проблема вот в чём:  
Пользователь вводит информацию через scanf()  
Если там 0, проверку сделать можно, а вот если там не число,  
Это я не знаю как сделать.

Comment: Создаешь переменную типа char, затем используй функцию atoi для перевода в целое (если там оно вообще есть).

Comment: <i>Пользователь вводит информацию через scanf()
Если там 0, проверку сделать можно, а вот если там не число,</i>

Очень просто. Сначала считываете строку. Затем разбираете ее вручную. Можно ф-цией `sscanf`, а можно `atoi`. Еще обратите внимание, что `scanf` и его производные возвращают кол-во успешно преобразованных элементов.

Comment: To @byte :

Ваш первый пример кода на Си выдает **warning** (а собственно Вы *действительно хотели* извлечь младший байт указателя ?). 

Второй пример кода - **error** - ну, в самом деле, как преобразовать 64-х разрядное число в формате с плавающей точкой в машинный адрес ???

Обычно у компилятора нет телепатических способностей и понять, что на самом деле хотел программист он не может.

Comment: @avp Спасибо, поправил.

Answer (score 3):

typeid возвращает объект типа [typeinfo](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/typeinfo/type_info/) из которого можно извлечь информацию о типе, но это C++.

Answer (score 1):

1. scanf отправляет введенные данные в массив чаров.
2. с помощью цикла и функции isdigit (из ctype.h) проверить каждый элемент массива, является ли он цифрой. Можно ввести еще одно условие - разделитель (точка или запятая) для вещественных чисел.
3. Если не цифра или не разделитель, прерываем цикл и говорим, что введено не число. Если же все элементы массива ОК и достигнут нуль-терминирующий элемент, делаем с ним, что нужно: переводим в int, float  и т.д. по своему усмотрению.